# Contact Provider using View Model and Live Data

Tags: android-architecture-components, android-livedata

My android app is using `contacts providers` to display all the contacts to the user. I'm using `Loaders` to load the contacts by following the tutorial/documentation at https://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-names

But from the link https://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders, it is mentioned that loaders are deprecated as of Android P.

> Loaders have been deprecated as of Android P (API 28). The recommended
>   option for dealing with loading data while handling the Activity and
>   Fragment lifecycles is to use a combination of ViewModels and
>   LiveData. ViewModels survive configuration changes like Loaders but
>   with less boilerplate. LiveData provides a lifecycle-aware way of
>   loading data that you can reuse in multiple ViewModels. You can also
>   combine LiveData using MediatorLiveData, and any observable queries,
>   such as those from a Room database, can be used to observe changes to
>   the data. ViewModels and LiveData are also available in situations
>   where you do not have access to the LoaderManager, such as in a
>   Service. Using the two in tandem provides an easy way to access the
>   data your app needs without having to deal with the UI lifecycle. To
>   learn more about LiveData see the LiveData guide and to learn more
>   about ViewModels see the ViewModel guide.

So my question is:

**1. How can we fetch the contacts using android view Model and live data from contact providers?**
**2. Can we use Room database for contact providers?**

Below you can find the link to the source code where I tried to use the Android View Model and Live data to fetch the contacts from ContactProviders.

https://github.com/deepak786/phonebook-contacts
**3. What can be improved in the above source code so that fetching will be faster?**

Thanks & Regards
Deepak

Comment: found any solution?

Comment: Not yet, but I tried it. Please check the repo https://github.com/deepak786/phonebook-contacts

Answer (score 5):

Below you can find a very simple solution for loading contacts using `MVVM`:

https://github.com/NaarGes/Android-Contact-List

Here comes a bit of code in case the link is no longer working.

First, let's create a simple `POJO` for contacts **UserObject.java**

```java
public class UserObject {

    private String email, name, phone;

    public UserObject() {
        // EMPTY CONSTRUCTOR FOR FIREBASE REALTIME DATABASE
    }

    public UserObject(String email, String name, String phone) {
        this.email = email;
        this.name = name;
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }
}
```

Now, let's create our repository **ContactRepository.java**

```java
public class ContactRepository {

    private Context context;

    private static final String TAG = "debinf ContRepo";

    public ContactRepository(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public List<UserObject> fetchContacts() {
        List<UserObject> contacts = new ArrayList<>();

        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        Log.i(TAG, "fetchContacts: cursor.getCount() is "+cursor.getCount());
        if ((cursor != null ? cursor.getCount() : 0) > 0) {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

                String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                String phone = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

                UserObject contact = new UserObject("",name, phone);

                Log.i(TAG, "fetchContacts: phone is "+phone);

                contacts.add(contact);
            }
        }
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
        return contacts;
    }
}
```

Next, we create our **ContactViewModel.java**

```java
public class ContactViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private ContactRepository repository;
    private MutableLiveData<List<UserObject>> contacts;

    public ContactViewModel(Context context) {
        repository = new ContactRepository(context);
        contacts = new MutableLiveData<>();
    }

    public MutableLiveData<List<UserObject>> getContacts() {
        contacts.setValue(repository.fetchContacts());
        return contacts;
    }
}
```

Next, we create a `factory` for our `ViewModel` **ContactViewModelFactory.java**

```java
public class ContactViewModelFactory implements ViewModelProvider.Factory {

    private Context context;

    public ContactViewModelFactory(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public <T extends ViewModel> T create(@NonNull Class<T> modelClass) {
        if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(ContactViewModel.class)) {
            return (T) new ContactViewModel(context);
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown ViewModel class");
    }
}
```

Let's not forget to add permission in our `AndroidManifest`

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

And finally, we ask for permission in our **MainActivity.java**

```java
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS,Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, PERMISSION_REQUEST);
}
```

and bring our contacts to surface

```java
ContactViewModelFactory factory = new ContactViewModelFactory(this);
viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, factory).get(ContactViewModel.class);

viewModel.getContacts().observe(this, new Observer<List<UserObject>>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(@Nullable List<UserObject> userObjects) {
        Log.i(TAG, "ViewModel: userObjects size is "+userObjects.size());
        Log.i(TAG, "ViewModel: userObjects size is "+userObjects.get(1).getPhone());
    }
});
```

Comment: @Selvin, I think it would be a good practice to fetch contacts, by using background task in **ContactRepository.java**.

Comment: not only good practice ... there is no sense of using LiveData when everthing is done on UI thread

Comment: Passing activity context to viewModel with causing memory leak

Comment: Thank you, @AhmedM.Abdalla ! Maybe it is more appropriated to use AndroidViewModel which has static application instance right away.

Answer (score 0):

```
class ContactsViewModel(private val contentResolver: ContentResolver) : ViewModel() 
{

    lateinit var contactsList: LiveData<PagedList<Contact>>

    fun loadContacts() {
        val config = PagedList.Config.Builder()
                .setPageSize(20)
                .setEnablePlaceholders(false)
                .build()
        contactsList = LivePagedListBuilder<Int, Contact>(
                ContactsDataSourceFactory(contentResolver), config).build()
    }
}

class ContactsDataSourceFactory(private val contentResolver: ContentResolver) :
        DataSource.Factory<Int, Contact>() {

    override fun create(): DataSource<Int, Contact> {
        return ContactsDataSource(contentResolver)
    }
}

class ContactsDataSource(private val contentResolver: ContentResolver) :
        PositionalDataSource<Contact>() {

    companion object {
        private val PROJECTION = arrayOf(
                ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY
        )
    }

    override fun loadInitial(params: LoadInitialParams, callback: LoadInitialCallback<Contact>) {
        callback.onResult(getContacts(params.requestedLoadSize, params.requestedStartPosition), 0)
    }

    override fun loadRange(params: LoadRangeParams, callback: LoadRangeCallback<Contact>) {
        callback.onResult(getContacts(params.loadSize, params.startPosition))
    }

    private fun getContacts(limit: Int, offset: Int): MutableList<Contact> {
        val cursor = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                PROJECTION,
                null,
                null,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY +
                        " ASC LIMIT " + limit + " OFFSET " + offset)

        cursor.moveToFirst()
        val contacts: MutableList<Contact> = mutableListOf()
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast) {
            val id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(PROJECTION[0]))
            val lookupKey = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(PROJECTION[0]))
            val name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(PROJECTION[2]))
            contacts.add(Contact(id, lookupKey, name))
            cursor.moveToNext()
        }
        cursor.close()

        return contacts
    }
}
```

Please find the full source code [here](https://github.com/anujmiddha/paged-list-demo).

Comment: what is the use of LiveData if query is done directly on UI thraead?

Comment: @AtomicBoolean what is the logic if a new contact is inserted in phonebook? Will it add duplicate Contacts in MutableList again if getContacts gets called? I think a new list will be returned according to the code. Is the getContact method called everytime the activity starts and viewmodel gets called i.e creating a new mutablelist everytime the activity starts? What is the correct ans?